# Flutter - unable to parse json array

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter

I want to fetch list of cities from rest webservice, this way:

```
Future<List<City>> fetchCities() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('https://my-url/city',
  headers: {HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: "application/json"});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    return compute(parseCities, response.body);
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load cities');
  }
}
```

Then to parse:

```
List<City> parseCities(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody)['data']['children'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<City>((json) => City.fromJson(json['data'])).toList();
}
```

And this is `City` class definition:

```
class City {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  City({this.id, this.name});

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return City(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

My example `responseBody` is:

```
[{\"id\":\"599\",\"name\":\"Bia\u0142ystok-dev\",\"location\":{\"long\":\"23.15\",\"lat\":\"53.13\"}}]
```

(for now, I want to ommit `location` and only fetch id and name). My `json.decode` throws exception:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

How to fix that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json string you have posted does not contain the keys `data` or `children` so to parse that json you would need to change your parse method to the following:

```
List<City> parseCities(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<City>((json) => City.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

although I think its good practice to use `List.from` instead of `.cast`

```
final parsed = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(responseBody));
```